# How to generate the mapping table in a many to many insert

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have a table of trades for Companys in an exchange. So for a given day I can have many trades for a company. I now want to take these trades and group them into positions.

A trade can below to many positions depending on its attributes like country, type etc
a position can be made up of many trades.

So I have the following tables

**Table Trades**

```
Id   Date      Company   Trade  Type
1 2012-11-01     IBM     1000    A
2 2012-11-01     IBM     3000    B
3 2012-11-01     Dell    1000    A
4 2012-11-01     HP      5000    A
5 2012-11-01     HP      6000    A
6 2012-11-01     HP      7000    B
```

**Table TradePositionMapping**

```
PK     TableTradeID      PositionID
1          1                100      --IBM 1000
2          1                101      --IBM 1000
3          2                101      --IBM 3000
4          3                102      --Dell 1000
5          4                103      --HP 5000
6          5                103      --HP 6000
7          4                104      --Hp 5000
7          5                104      --Hp 6000
7          6                104      --Hp 7000
```

**Table Position**

```
PK   Company Position
100   IBM      1000
101   IBM      4000
102   Dell     1000
103   Hp      11000
104   Hp      18000
```

So in the Positions above the IBM Trade ID 1 went to 2 Positions 100 and 101. Trade Id 2 also went to Position 101 giving a total of 4000

Ok so the idea being that a trade can make up 1 or more positions and a position can have many trades. The business logic will determine what positions the trades flow to, so I have used A and B as flags for now just as an example.

So to the question which is..

When I select and aggregate from the Trades Table, I insert all the new positions that are made up from the various trades into the Positions table. Now what is the best way to create the mapping table.

What I do at the moment is that I store the newly created Position Ids in a tempory table and then repeat the select that I would do to generate the postions in the first place.. and join to the tempory table. THis seems like a lot of duplication of code and I would like to know what the best practice is out there to do such a thing.

best regards Mick

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding. Can you clarify which tables are your source data, which tables you are generating, and how they all fit together. it's difficult to understand the joins between the tables based on those field names. For example it appears from your description that you are generating 'Positions' from 'Trades' and then you want to generate 'TradePositionMapping', but how do you get Position.Position (100,101 etc.) without Mapping.PositionID in the first place?

Comment: Thanks Mitch.. we all cant be as good as you my friend I guess

Comment: ElectricLlama, thanks for the response and please apologies if my example was vague. So my source Table is the Trade Table. I aggregate these up and create positions in the positions table. I then need to join Positions and Trades to show the many to many relation. At the moment I do this by pushing the new PK for the insert to the positions table into a temporary table. I then more or less call the same code again to select the Trade records and join to the temporary table with the new Position PK's. I just want to know is there a better way to do it. Hope this helps and thanks for looking -M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after more research, it seems the approach that I take is the best approach. The 2 schools of thought when creating a mapping to join source rows in one table to aggregated rows in another table is to either

1 Iteriate through the source row and use a cursor to process the groups of data. Then insert 1 aggregated record in the Destination table and build in the Mappings in the Mapping table with the new ID. However this can be expensive with cursors.

2 The other approach and the approach that I take is to lift and aggregate the data from the source tables and bulk insert into the Destination table, storing the new ID's in a temp table variable. The trick is to ensure that you also copy in the criteria that you grouped on as you need this to join the records together to create the mapping.

So as an example:

:Direction being L for Long and S for short
:PK are identity columns in all tables

:didnt have time to build proper code so please excuse any syntax errors.

**Table Trades**  -- this is our source table

```
    TradeId    Date      Company   Trade  Direction
    10      2012-11-01     IBM     1000         L
    20      2012-11-01     IBM     3000         L
    30      2012-11-01     IBM     5000         S
    40      2012-11-01     Dell    1000         S
    50      2012-11-01     Dell    2000         S
    60      2012-11-01     Dell    3000         S
    70      2012-11-01     HP      5000         L
    80      2012-11-01     HP      6000         L
    90      2012-11-01     HP      7000         S
    100     2012-11-02     ORA     1000         S
    110     2012-11-02     ORA     1000         S
    120     2012-11-02     ORA     1000         S
```

so select all the Trades and aggregate them based on company and direction

```
declare @feedDate DateTime = '2012-11-01'  -- feed date to run for
declare @newPositionIds Table (newPositionId bigint)  -- temp table to store new PositionId

-- Aggregate and insert the trades only for the feed date. ORA should not be processed
Insert into Position (Company, Direction, Position)
 Output inserted.PositionID         
  Into @newPositionIds (newPositionId)
select Company, Direction, sum(Trade)
  from Trade t where t.date = @feedDate 
    group by Company, Direction
```

This should add these records to the Positions table

**Table Position**

```
    PositionID   Company Position   Direction    
    100             IBM      4000         L
    200             IBM      5000         S
    300             Dell     6000         S
    400             Hp      11000         L
    500             Hp      7000          S
```

ok Now we want to fill out the Mapping table with the records that where used to aggregate each position

So we need to join the Trades to the postions but we need to use the same criteria that we used to group by. This is why we need to insert that criteria into the position table

So this time we select all the Trades but dont sum them and join to the position table.. then insert the result into the mapping table. So this is done by build 2 derived tables in the query.. 1 for the trades and the other for the positions and joining them on the criteria used to group them in the first place. All we need from these 2 queries is the PK Id's

```
-- Select Trades for the feed date. ORA should not be included
Insert into TradePositionMapping(t.TradeID, p.PositionID)
(  select TradeId, Company, Direction, Trade            -- select the Trades
      from Trade t where t.date = @feedDate ) t
inner join
               -- join to temp table as we are only interested in the new ids we inserted
(select PositionId, Company,Direction from Position pos  
    inner join @newPositionIds npIds on pos.PositionId = npIds.newPositionIds
) p
on t.Company = p.Company and t.Direction = p.Direction
```

This should give us the following Mapping table

**Table TradePositionMapping** - TPM

```
    TPM_PK   TradeID      PositionID
    1          10            100      --IBM 1000  L
    2          20            100      --IBM 3000  L
    3          30            200      --IBM 5000  S
    4          40            300      --Dell 1000 S
    5          50            300      --Dell 2000 S
    6          60            300      --Dell 3000 S
    7          70            400      --Hp 5000   L
    7          80            400      --Hp 6000   L
    7          90            500      --Hp 7000   S
```

So instead of joining to the Positions to the tempory table we could also have brought over the feed date as criteria and joined to that but the temp table also works fine as I dont want the date file in my positions table

So now I can see what Trades made up what Positions using the mapping table.

I hope this helps anyone looking a bulk inserts on and generating mapping tables.

regards M

Comment: As Krystian mentioned below.. this of course should all be wrapped in a nice little transaction :-)

Comment: Just as an update, from a performance point of view, when processing larger data sets SQL seemed to have a problem on performance when creating the mapping table as it was joining a derived table with no Indexes. So as a work around what I did was I lifted all the data I needed to aggregate into a tempory table and then used that temporary table to sum and group to create the position records and insert the new Position Id's into a temp table. Then it was a matter of joining these 2 temp tables rather than rerunning the query to create the mappings.

Comment: This reduced the time it took to run normally from 3 mins to under a second :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a simple table TradePositionMapping with TableTradeID, PositionID.

Then according to your business logic:
(0.) Begin Transaction
1. Insert position
2. Get PositionID
3. Insert TableTradeID,PositionID pairs to TradePositionMapping
(4.) Commit

It should be this simple as than.

You can calculate sum of the position in advance to inserting or update it just before commit.

Comment: thanks Krystian for commenting... yes the approach you have would work well if I was doing this on a record by record basis, but what I am doing is lifting a heap of records and aggregating them together and inserting many records into the parent table. I then need to map these back to create the join

Comment: hi Krystian, if you get the chance can you look at what I added as an answer. Hopefully this explains my question better. The only thing I need to do of course is wrap it all in a transaction. Thanks again - M